# how to work arround authorization in echosign

Tags: meteor, echosign

I'm doing oauth in echo sign and have come across following steps.

1. App makes a get request to echosign along with the return url.

   ex: https://secure.echosign.com/public/oauth?redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauthDemo&
   response_type=code&client_id=d4HQNPFIXFD255H&scope=user_login:self+agreement_send:account

Echosign, asks the user to login to echosign and on success it appends code to the return url and sends back.

2. Taking the code from the return url, another post call is made to get the access token using which , api calls can be further made.

   POST call to /oauth/token
3. On this success, token-access has been generated successfully.

The things here is, how can i bypass the step where user will not have to login to echosign. Is there other easier way to get the access-token, seems like, code needs to be generated each time to get a new access-token.

I'm working on meteor, angularjs. Also i couldnt find any working examples on js, is there any ?
Please correct any of my steps.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to bypass the user to login but this needs to be done only once.

3. At this step you get the access token, refresh token and expiry time in seconds.
4. Check if your access token has expired and if so then use your refresh token to get a new access token. You can use the refresh token indefinitely until the EchoSign user manually revokes your application's token.
5. User your access token to make API calls.

PS: I don't know any working examples in JS.